# Best way to create an image slide app

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a super simple application for appstore with Swift 2.

The idea is that the user launches the app, and they immediately see a picture. They tap the picture and another one appears.

I want the app to store about 200++ pictures and i'll be adding more in updates.

So my question is: How do i tell Swift to display a new picture each time the user clicks the screen? How can i make it so that swift grabs the pictures from a folder within xcode without me needing to specifically call for each unique picture by its name?

I know how to create this app in Spritekit. But it seems like an extremely un-efficient way to add every single picture as a node, etc.

So if you have any ideas of slideshow frameworks / plugin or anything similar, id be really happy!

Answer (score 2):

First. You drag the `imageview` in your `mainstoryboard`.

If you want to interact with images, use `gesture`, just drag the `gesture` to the image. Then control click and reference the action of gesture to your viewcontroller and also reference the outlet of the image.

then you set the action for it, get the image in the folder like this:

```
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
var getImagePath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("filename")
myImageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: getImagePath)
```

Name your image from 1 to 200 like 1.png, 2.png...

Then in code just create a variable, then each time you click on the image, just `++` it.

Comment: Thank you, your comment gave me some clarity. However i have never touched anything other than spritekit, single page application is all new to me. Can you point me in the right direction? Do you know any youtube tutorial which grasps a similar concept? I'm getting lost at "Then control click and reference the action of gesture to your viewcontroller and also reference the outlet of the image." Like, what does this do? Why? Where do i find the gestures "code-area" where i put the "NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains"-code? I'm sorry, so many questions.

Comment: Well, First thing, just do as I said, don't care that code. If my answer helpful with you, just upvote to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a image view in storyboard and a button over it (without anything on it of course)

you can then create a action for the button to change the image.
to do it you need to make a outlet for the image view too.